# Update multiple columns from a specific row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have seen examples of updating multiple rows from a join, but in this case there are more than one matching rows resulting from a join, I need a specific row (the earliest UpdatedDate row).

Example of the tables:

[Robot]

```
RobotNumber         RobotName    RobotColor      UpdatedDate   
1                   XA01         Red             01/01/2020
2                   B1205        Purple          02/02/2020
3                   ZP344        Orange          03/03/2020
```

[RobotAuditTable]

```
RobotNumber         RobotName    RobotColor      UpdatedDate   
1                   XA01         Yellow          1/1/2019
1                   XA01         Red             2/2/2020
```

I want to update the RobotName XA01 with the values(RobotName, RobotColor) from the earliest Updated Date row in the RobotAuditTable.

I have tried approaches with joins and subqueries but I cannot get the syntax and conditions correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
update r
    set r.robotname = rat.robotname,
        r.robotcolor = rat.robotcolor        
    from robot r cross apply
         (select top (1) rat.*
          from robotaudittable rat
          where rat.robotnumber = r.robotnumber
          order by rat.updateddate asc
         ) rat;
```